# Overloading logical operators considered bad practice?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, logical-operators

Is it a bad idea to overload &&, || or comma operator and Why?

Comment: this feels like a final exam question ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't overload `operator&&` or `operator||`. Even if you define a class that gives rise to a Boolean algebra (finite sets, for example), it would probably be a better choice to overload `operator&` and `operator|`.

The reason is that C++ programmers expect special semantics for `operator&&` and `operator||`: they are *short-circuited*, i.e. don't evaluate their right-hand argument if not necessary. You can't get this behavior by overloading, since you'll be defining a function.

Overloading `operator,` has been done in e.g. the [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library. This is also the only example of its overloading that I know, and I've never even considered overloading it myself. You'd better have a very specific use case for it where no other operator is suited.

Comment: good point. So, it seems that it is better to provide an operator for conversion to bool in such case (`operator bool()`)?

Comment: @davka: Yes, define `operator bool` if your class has Boolean logic semantics, that gives you short-circuiting for free. Define `operator&` and `operator|` if it has Boolean algebra semantics, like finite sets do (where intersection is `&`, union is `|`).

Comment: @larsmans: Terribly sorry, an accidental click. I had to "edit" your answer to remove it (i removed a whitespace line).

Comment: @davka: regarding the bool conversion... no don't! See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html, the major issue is that a bool can be promoted to integers. It's better to define a conversion operator to a pointer to member-function.

Answer (score 4):

For overloading the logical operators in C++, the operands must be evaluated, which isn't the way things normally work with short circuiting of built-in types.

Look at the below link.

- [Don't overload logical operators in C++](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS62/L09slides/lecture.html#L09_220_logical)

Answer (score 3):

It is usually a bad idea: those three operators have a sequencing effect which is lost when you overload them.  Loosing that sequencing effect can cause arm (i.e. strange bugs) to those not expecting that lost.

There are cases with template expressions where you can keep the sequencing effect, in those cases I see no problem in overloading them.

The overloads of `operator,` I know of have another problem: they work in such a way that the apparent chains of operation isn't the real one.  Usually, they are used in context when it makes no difference, but once in a blue moon, that is another source of a strange bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't overload any operators in a way that is surprising. :-)

If you can do it in a way that makes sense (not only to you), it is fine to do so.

Like others have said, the logical operators are special in that they have the effect of lazy evaluation. So your overloads should probably preserve this lazy effect, like with expression templates, or only be used where people don't expect this effect anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on what your overloads are doing. For example, && and || are expected to work as logical conditions, so if your overload semantics work somehow differently, they can confuse other people (or even yourself, if you don't use them for a while and forget what they do). Consider what you would expect the operators to do if you wouldn't know how they are overloaded and if it would be clearer to just use normal methods instead.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, missing lazy evaluation is the main reason to avoid overloading logical operators.

However, there is one very good reason to overload them: [Expression templates](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template). The Boost.Lambda library does this, and it's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea except situations when your classes represents some logic entity, because overloaded operators will disorientate and can cause new bugs in code.

Comment: Even when you're defining "logical entities" (Boolean algebras), other operators are better suited.