# Error c6277 overloading && in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

In my class I have member functions:

```
const bool operator&&(const KinematicVariable &right) const { 
        return this->isUsed() && right.isUsed(); 
}
inline const bool isUsed() const { return this->_used; }
```

then I try

```
if (k1 && k2 && k3)
```

But I get

```
error: C2677: binary '&&' : no global operator found which takes type 
'KinematicVariable' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Is this inside the `KinematicVariable` class? You have to have one for (bool, const KinematicVariable &) as well because the first call returns a bool to be used with the second.

Comment: Yea it is, right inside the header.

Comment: FYI, overloading `&&` or `||` is [considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133114/overloading-logical-operators-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, `k1 && k2` will be evaluated to a boolean value, and then you will have `that_bool && k3`, which you do not provide an overload of `operator&&` for ([and shouldn't!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133114/150634)). It seems that what you really want to do is not overload anything at all:

```
if (k1.isUsed() && k2.isUsed() && k3.isUsed())
```

Alternatively, you *could* provide a explicit conversion to `bool` as a member of `KinematicVariable`:

```
explicit operator bool() const { return isUsed(); }
```

To do this in C++03, use the [safe-bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).