# Elegant way for "if(T t = ...) { } else return t;"?

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

Is there a better way for this "idiom"?

```
if(State s = loadSomething()) { } else return s;
```

In other words, I want to do something, which may return an error (with a message) or a success state, and if there was an error I want to return it. This can become very repetitive, so I want to shorten it. For example

```
if(State s = loadFoobar(&loadPointer, &results)) { } else return s;
if(State s = loadBaz(&loadPointer, &results)) { } else return s;
if(State s = loadBuz(&loadPointer, &results)) { } else return s;
```

This must not use exceptions which I would favor otherwise (unsuitable for this build). I could write up a little class `BooleanNegator<State>` that stores the value, and negates its boolean evaluation. But I want to avoid doing this ad-hoc, and prefer a boost/standard solution.

Comment: I suppo se that State has a bool operator, right?

Comment: @Brahim right, that's true

Comment: and you don't want to elevate the scope of `s` outside the `if` block, correct?

Comment: @CoryKramer right. In the success case, there is some information like the load address of the loaded element and some stuff, which I don't always need.

Comment: If your `load*` succeeds, what do you return?

Comment: @black the result then is what was written into @c results.

Comment: What's the type of `result` then? I'm missing something otherwise...

Comment: @black it's just something where the results are pushed in. like "Foobar*" or "Baz*" that get assigned whatever was loaded. Ultimately, I'm searching for a pattern to do this for the general case where there is a `if(T t = ...)` for arbitrary values of `...`. In most cases, if something is false then we have an  empty/null case and only one "value" I think (shared_ptr, optional, ...). But in my case and perhaps other cases, the empty/null/fail case may have supplementary values I want to process.

Comment: If only you could've done something like `if(State s = loadSomething(), !s)`
At this point, the best solution might be to wrap one of the "noisy" solutions in a macro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do:

```
for (State s = loadSomething(); !s; ) return s;
```

but I am not sure if it is more elegant, and it is definitely less readable...

Comment: Ah it's definitely creative!

Comment: interesting! :) but I think I wouldn't like to see it in the code I mantain :P

Answer (score 3):

I assume the context is something like

```
State SomeFunction()
{
     if(State s = loadSomething()) { } else return s;
     return do_something_else();
}
```

without throwing exceptions where `do_something_else()` does something of relevance to `SomeFunction()` and returns a `State`.   Either way, the result of continuing within the function needs to result in a `State` being returned, as falling off the end will cause the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour.

In that case, I would simply restructure the function to

```
State SomeFunction()
{
     if (State s = loadSomething())
        return do_something_else();
     else
        return s;
}
```

Implicit assumptions are that `State` has some operator (e.g. `operator bool()`) that can be tested, that copying a `State` is possible (implied by the existence of a `loadSomething()` that returns one) and relatively inexpensive, and that two instances of `State` can exist at one time.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from some smart/hacky uses of different keywords to get the same behavior, or adding more-or-less complex extra templates or macros to get `unless()` keyword or to somehow manage to inject `!` operator, I'd stick to just the basic things.

This is one of the places I'd (*probably*) inject extra "unnecessary" brackets:

```
void someFunction()
{
    // some other code

    { State s = loadSomething(); if(!s) return s; }

    // some other code
}
```

However, in this exact case, I'd expand it to emphasise the `return` keyword, which can be easily overlooked when it's squashed to a one-liner. So, unless the one-liner is repeated many times and unless it's clear&obvious that there's a `return` inside, I'd probably write:

```
void someFunction()
{
    // some other code

    {
        State s = loadSomething();
        if(!s)
            return s;
    }

    // some other code
}
```

It might look like elevating the scope of the `s`, but actually it is equivalent to declaring `State s` in `if()`. All thanks to the extra brackets which explicitly limit the visibility of local `s`.

However, some people just "hate" seeing `{ .. }` not coupled with a keyword/class/function/etc, or even consider it to be unreadable due to "suggesting that a if/while/etc keyword was accidentally deleted".

One more idea came to me after you added the repetitive example. You could have tried a trick known from scripting languages where `&&` and `||` may return a non-bool values:

```
State s = loadFoobar(&loadPointer, &results);
s = s || loadBaz(&loadPointer, &results);
s = s || loadBuz(&loadPointer, &results);
if(!s) return s;
```

however there's a problem: in contrast to script languages, in C++ such overloads of `&&` and `||` [lose their short-circuit semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133114/overloading-logical-operators-considered-bad-practice) which makes this attempt pointless.

However, as **dyp** pointed out the obvious thing, once the `s` scope is elevated, now simple `if` can be introduced back. Its visibility can be limited back again with extra `{}`:

```
{
    State s;
    if(!(s = loadFoobar(&loadPointer, &results))) return s;
    if(!(s = loadBaz(&loadPointer, &results))) return s;
    if(!(s = loadBuz(&loadPointer, &results))) return s;
}
```

Comment: `s || (s = loadBaz(..));` should work fine: there's no need to overload `||` in this case, we only need a conversion from `State` to `bool` (which we already have).

Comment: @dyp: seems I've overlooked the obvious! thank you! I'll weave it into the post