# Overloading operator&& it's return type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I have the following general class:

```
class Example
{
public:
  Example(std::string _a): a(_a) {}
  std::string a;
}
```

I want to overload the operator&& and || to be able to do something like this:

```
Example test("a"),test2("b"),test3("c");
std::string result = test && test2 || test3;
```

and the result will be: "a&&b||c"

Comment: Yes, you can specify any return type when you overload an operator.

Comment: For example, `std::filesystem` have overloaded `operator/` for concatenating pathes to one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash. So yeah, you can choose return type as you wish

Comment: Make them return `Example`.

Comment: I got it, thanks you, didn't know you can change the return type. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: [Do not overload logical operators.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133114/overloading-logical-operators-considered-bad-practice)